# having contains in struts2 iterator tag

Tags: struts2

I have the following code which does not seem to work. I fail to see why this wont work.

```
<s:iterator value=%{questions} id="question">
   <s:if test='%{incorrectQs.contains("#question.questionId")}'>
      Print something here
   </s:if>
</s:iterator>
```

In the above code, basically I have a method called getQuestions in the action class.  This list contains objects of Exam class which has a get/set questionId.  I also have incorrectQs list which contains strings.  I am checking if incorrectQs contains a questionId. if it does i want to print some text. Eventhough, the above code does not work, the code below works fine randomly.  Sometimes it works and sometimes it does not...:(

```
<s:iterator value=%{questions}>
   <s:if test='%{incorrectQs.contains("${questionId}")}'>
      Print something here
   </s:if>
</s:iterator>
```

can anyone provide some insight in this?

Comment: Is the questionId property of Exam a string?  If it's not, then it's probably a type conversion issue.  The String equals method (which will be called by the List contains method) won't return true if you pass an Integer in (or any other non-String), even if the value of the string equals the toString() value of the Integer.

Comment: is there a way to actually check the type??

Comment: You should be able to set a breakpoint on the getQuestionId() method in your Exam class, and follow it from there.

Comment: it helps to accept an answer - or if you answered it yourself to enter it for future vistors

Comment: Struts2 syntax is a hot mess! Try converting to JSP variables with `<s:set var="myQuestion" value="%{question}"/><jsp:useBean id="myQuestion"/>` and use scriptlets. At least you will know what is going on. The least you can do is enclose `value=%{questions}` in quotes like `value="%{questions}"`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your `Action` class looks like, but you can try something like this. When you're inside the `s:iterator` tag, I think each `%{foo}` expression will attempt to access the specific instance you are iterating (the question, not the List of questions).

*Note: There may be a way using `#` to reference the parent object from within the `s:iterator` tag. I just haven't done it, so can't say for sure if it would help you here.*

```
public class ActionClass ... {

    private List<Question> mQuestions;
    private Set<Integer> mIncorrectQuestions;

    public String execute() {
        // build/read questions, populate incorrect questions, etc...
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public List<Question> getQuestions() {
        return mQuestions;
    }

    // does not need to be an inner class
    public class Questions {

        private int mQuestionId;

        public int getQuestionId() {
            return mQuestionId;
        }

        public boolean getIsIncorrect() {
            return mIncorrectQuestions.contains(mQuestionId);
        }
}
```

And then in your JSP:

```
<s:iterator value='%{questions}'>
    <s:if test='%{isIncorrect}'>
        Question <s:property value='${questionId}'/> is Incorrect!
    </s:if>
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#question.questionId.toString()
```